# Providing pairs as argument to a function in python

Tags: python

I have done the following:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import numpy as np
z1 = np.random.random_sample(20)
z3 = np.random.random_sample(20)
z2 = np.random.random_sample((20,1))
regr_1 = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=None)
regr_1.fit(np.array([z1,z3]).T, z2)

regr_1.predict([5,10])
array([ 0.13316289])
```

I however want to now perform prediction over `z11` which is same as variable `z1` and `z31` which is same as `z3`.

`z11` and `z31` both have size `200x500`. The corresponding ith row and jth columns of both `Z11` and `z31` form a pair.

How do I perform the following kind of prediction:

```
pred = regr_1.predict([z11,z31])
```

`pred` should have size `200x500`

i.e how do I supply to function `regr_1.predict` the pairs from `z11` and `z31` so that function can work. Right now I get errors in the above method of implementation.

Edit: `z11` and `z31` are variables over which prediction needs done. So, kind of my out of sample data. There are 100,000 (200x500) pairs of `z11` and `z31`.

Comment: FYI, `foo((20))` passes a single integer argument, making it exactly the same as `foo(20)`; contrast with `foo((20,))`, which passes a single-item tuple. Which of those two do you want?

Comment: I tried following also and it gives same answer z1 = np.random.random_sample((20,))

Comment: Indeed. That doesn't change the truth of what I said above. (If I had a solution for your question, it would be posted as an answer, not a comment; that you're using an unnecessarily-verbose way of writing `z1 = np.random.random_sample(20)` stands as a comment on its own).

Comment: Fixed it as you pointed out :)

Comment: 1) Import the correct class. Do you want a spline or a Decision Tree? 2) `np.random.random_sample(20)` gives you a column vector with 20 rows. Slamming 2 together in a matrix and transposing them gives you an input matrix of 2x20. I don't understand where 200x500 comes from?